# Summarising (grouping and counting) a sequence of maps

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to find an idiomatic way in Clojure of grouping a sequence of maps by certain keys and providing counts. Sort of like 'SELECT X, Y, COUNT(*) FROM Z GROUP BY X, Y' in SQL. The data looks like this:

```
({:status "Academy Sponsor Led",
  :pupil-population "",
  :locality "Northamptonshire",
  :pupil-gender "Mixed",
  :county "Northamptonshire",
  :pupil-age "11-18",
  :school "Wrenn School",
  :website ""}
 {:status "Academy Sponsor Led",
  :pupil-population "915",
  :locality "Plymouth",
  :pupil-gender "Mixed",
  :county "Devon",
  :pupil-age "11-19",
  :school "The All Saints Church of England Academy",
  :website "http://www.asap.org.uk/"}
 {:status "Academy Converter",
  :pupil-population "735",
  :locality "Somerset",
  :pupil-gender "Mixed",
  :county "Somerset",
  :pupil-age "11-16",
  :school "Stanchester Academy",
  :website "www.Stanchester-Academy.co.uk"}
 {:status "Community School",
  :pupil-population "",
  :locality "Herefordshire",
  :pupil-gender "Mixed",
  :county "Herefordshire",
  :pupil-age "11-18",
  :school "Lady Hawkins High School",
  :website "http://www.lhs.hereford.sch.uk"}...
```

and my solution looks like this:

```
(defn summarise-locality-status
  "Return counts of status within locality"
  [data]
  (let [locality (group-by :locality data)
        locality-status (map #(vector (first %) (group-by :status (second %))) locality)
        counts-fn (fn [locality-status-item]
                    (let [statuses (second locality-status-item)]
                      (map #(vector % (count (get statuses %))) (keys statuses))))]
    (map #(vector (first %) (counts-fn %)) locality-status)))
```

However it feels a bit clunky. What would be better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs,

```
(frequencies (for [r data] (select-keys r [:locality :status])))
```

is closer to the SQL, in that it is not nested.

Comment: I don't think this works as intended, since duplicate groups will be removed, so `frequencies` will return `1` for each distinct `:locality`/`:status` pair, regardless of the input.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, introducing `juxt` and `reduce-kv`:

```
(->> data
     (group-by (juxt :locality :status))
     (reduce-kv #(assoc-in % %2 (count %3)) {}))
```

This might be closest to your original SQL and more intuitively understandable.

Comment: should be `(juxt :locality :status)` instead of `(juxt :status :locality)`

Comment: and to be honest, I've never seen `reduce-kv` before :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
(reduce #(update-in %1 [(:locality %2) (:status %2)] (fnil inc 0)) {} data)
```

or

```
(reduce #(update-in %1 ((juxt :locality :status) %2) (fnil inc 0)) {} data)
```

The output is a little different (hash maps instead of lists), but that's easy to change. Using a hash map makes `group-by` superfluous and the code a lot shorter/easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
(for [[locality statuses] (group-by :locality data)]
  {:locality locality :all_status
   (for [[status items] (group-by :status statuses)]
      {:status status :count (count items)})})
```